# How to keep iPod in shuffle mode after selecting a specific song?

Tags: iphone, ipod

I'm using the iPod on my iPhone 4 in shuffle mode. If I go back to songs menu and select a specific song, the iPod forgets that it is in shuffle mode. It will play the next song in alphabetical order.

Is there any way to make shuffle mode setting stickier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the screen when your in the iPod app once so that the scrubber bar appears. In the right corner is a shuffle button. Hit that and it should stick